# Sammy.js Rerun Same Route

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I have a page that does some vertical scrolling between information. I'm using sammy to navigate around it. But if someone manually scrolls up the page after clicking the link to get to a certain section of the page, then they click the same link again, the action doesn't run, because the hash is identical.

Here is a simplified example of the issue...

http://jsfiddle.net/Qya4j/1/

#### Javascript

```
$.sammy('body', function() {
  this.before(/.*/, function () {
  console.log('before');
});
  this.get('#/add/:number', function(context) {
    $("#content").append("badger");
  });
}).run();
```

#### HTML

```
<a href="#/add/1">Add One</a>
<a href="#/add/2">Add Two</a>
<br>
<div id="content">Badger hole.</div>
```

Is there some way to make the route run again with the same hash? Or is there some other way to approach this situation? I can see why this would be a bad idea for some applications, but when it comes to scrolling based navigation, this makes a lot of sense.

#### A Few Things I've Tried

Using `window.location.hash = window.location.hash + "?something"` within my route to just change the url, so it no longer matches exactly. This *would* work, except it spirals into an infinite loop and crashes the browser. Appending a different parameter manually to every link is an option, but is dumb for obvious reasons.

I've tried using an `after` callback with similar effects.

Comment: Why do you need Sammy for your vertical scrolling?

Comment: I certainly don't _need_ it, but I would like it to update the history so that people can use the forward and back buttons, and I also like the idea of building upon something with Sammy's brilliant routing that could keep things organized as the project grows.